# How to integrate olapic service to a web page?

Tags: service, integrate

How can I integrate an Olapic service into a web page?

Is there a manual where you can guide me or an API and examples that I can use as a basis?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Here http://developer.olapic.com/ & http://apiv2-docs.photorank.me/ you can find detailed info on how to use Olapic API. But you cannot create a test account you need to either purchase there service or request to give a demo.

Comment: why down vote? I answered correctly and we used olapic in our recent project.